# i am unable to pass array as function parameter.how i can solve?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a window form application and making a function pass an array as function parameter as shown below:

```
void foobar(int[] foo, string[] bar)
{ 

}
//calling
foobar(new {1, 2,3}, new {"a", "b", "c"});
```

when I call the function, it displays the error:

```
"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//calling
foobar(new int[] {1, 2,3}, new string[] {"a", "b", "c"});
```

Comment: An explanation of this would make this a better answer.

Comment: thank you.it is working well ...but why compiler not understand that the declared data type in function.?

Comment: @Ubaid compiler understands that you made a mistake, that's why you got appropriate compiler message. It correctly concluded you are trying to instantiate and initialize anonymous type - but it was wrongly defined, hence the compiler error. If you put `new { prop2 = 1, prop1 = 2}`, you'd get error that types are not matched between function and what you've passed.

Comment: its ok but my question was that firstly we define data type in function declearation and then also define while calling the function--need define datatype at calling time...why?.

Comment: It's not necessary to specify the type of elements if they are all of the same type. `new[] { 1, 2, 3 }` will work fine.

Comment: Just to be complete here. You can also use `new[]{1,2,3}` and `new[]{"a","b","c"}`. The compiler will understand what type you want it to use. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

`new {1, 2,3}` and `new {"a", "b", "c"}` are not valid (not the correct way to declare the array) in C#. So to pass an array you have to use proper syntax i.e. `new int[] {1, 2,3}, new string[] {"a", "b", "c"}`.